# ANSI C problem with dynamic array and scan string

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I got a problem with this small program in ANSI C. I want to make a program with three functions - make a dynamic array (stworz_tablice), load data - string (pobierz_tablice) and print it (wypisz_tablice).

So the program works like this: we give a number for our array, put a string and the function should write it at the console. For example, input: 4 Fire

How can I correct the code so it works?

I think the problem is with `mytab = stworz_tablice(n);`, but I have no clue yet how to fix it.

When I execute program it doesn't take a string. The output is like some random numbers instead of letters.

Input:

> 4 
>   Anna

The output I want:

> Anna

The output which I get every time:

> -24244 -24242 0 0 // Some random numbers, every time  different ones

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

char *stworz_tablice(int n)
{
    char *mytab = (char*)malloc((n+1) * sizeof(char));
    if (mytab == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error in malloc");
        exit (1);
    }
    return mytab;
}

void pobierz_tablice(char *mytab, int n)
{
    scanf ("%s", mytab);
}

void wypisz_tablice(char mytab[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%c",mytab[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int *mytab;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n<=0)
    {
        printf("BŁĄD");
        return 0;
    }

    mytab = stworz_tablice(n);
    pobierz_tablice(mytab, n);
    wypisz_tablice(mytab, n);

    putchar('\n');
    free(mytab);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem you face now?

Comment: You seem to have a 'typo'! In `main` you have `int *mytab;` but all three functions expect `char *mytab;`.

Comment: When I execute program it doesn't take string. Output is like some random numbers instead letters.
@AdrianMole - My bad, I was checking every option and I forgot to change it. Anyway switching to char doesn't change outcome. It's still wrong.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what's "wrong?" (Also, you need `#include <stdio.h>`.) With that included, your code seems to run fine on my IDE/PC. (Other than not properly representing `BŁĄD` in simple characters.)

Comment: @AdrianMole it compiles, but output is wrong and I don't know the reason. I edited main post to give example for output and input.

Comment: Don't cast the result of a call to `malloc()` etc. - it is unnecessary, and can hide the serious error of failing to have a correct prototype in scope. And `sizeof(char)` is by definition 1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

https://godbolt.org/z/zj_QpY

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *stworz_tablice(int n)
{
    char *mytab = malloc(n+1); 
    if (mytab == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error in malloc");
        exit (1);
    }
    return mytab;
}

int pobierz_tablice(char *mytab, int n)
{
    return scanf ("%s", mytab);
}

void wypisz_tablice(char mytab[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%c",mytab[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    char *mytab;
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n<=0)
    {
        printf("BŁĄD");
        return 0;
    }

    mytab = stworz_tablice(n);
    if(pobierz_tablice(mytab, n) != 1)
    {
        perror("Scanf error\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    wypisz_tablice(mytab, n);

    putchar('\n');
    free(mytab);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. So char *mytab = (char*)malloc((n+1) * sizeof(char));  would be fine for int instead of char? Also I noticed that  in line 8 if I change char *mytab = malloc(n); to malloc(n+4) or -3 or whatever it doesn't change anything with end result.

Comment: @dyn Not sure what you are asking with that comment. In C `sizeof char` is always 1. Therefore `(n+1)*sizeof(char)` is exactly the same as `n+1`. You only need `sizeof` for types different than `char`. The `+1` is needed to include space for the terminating 0 byte for your string. Your main problem is not the size of this memory allocation but your missing headers.

Comment: @dvn if you allocate less memory than needed it is Undefiend Behaviour. Anything can happen including that it will work OK. But the same program on another computer will not.

Comment: An explanation would be in order.